# pandas to_excel export corrupt file in docker?

Tags: python, pandas, docker, dropbox-api

I have a script that scrapes some information, puts it in a dataframe and writes it to an excel file in dropbox.
Now my program is running perfectly fine on my local computer but once I build a docker image of my project, the saved excel file comes out corrupted.

```
def write_excel_to_dropbox(dbx, df, excel_path):

    with io.BytesIO() as stream:

        with pd.ExcelWriter(stream) as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
            writer.save()

        stream.seek(0)

        dbx.files_upload(stream.getvalue(), excel_path, mode=dropbox.files.WriteMode.overwrite)
```

This is my function for writing and saving the excel file to my dropbox. It does actually save something but the file is corrupt. This is not the case when I run the script in pycharm.
Does anybody know what's happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had to change the engine to 'xlsxwriter'

`with pd.ExcelWriter(stream, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:`
Happy this fixed my problem but still not sure why it did run on my local and not in docker.